# Returning a pointer of a global struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a global struct defining a protocol rule as follows

```
const struct schc_rule_t schc_rule_1 = { 0x01, &compression_rule_1, NOT_FRAGMENTED, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

All rules are grouped together in an array

```
const struct schc_rule_t* node2_schc_rules[] = { &schc_rule_1 };
```

Which can than be assigned to a device

```
const struct schc_device node2 = { 2, 1, &node2_schc_rules};
```

Of which the `struct` looks like

```
struct schc_device {
    uint32_t device_id;
    uint8_t rule_count;
    const struct schc_rule_t *(*context)[];
};
```

All of these arrays are defined globally, as I'm implementing this for an embedded device and want to store as many variables as possible in the `.text` section (I'm not sure whether this is best practice, but this will do for now).

Now,
I have a lookup function that tries to find a rule for a particular device

```
struct schc_rule_t* get_schc_rule_by_rule_id(uint8_t rule_id, uint32_t device_id) {
    int i;
    struct schc_device *device = get_device_by_id(device_id);

    if (device == NULL) {
        DEBUG_PRINTF("get_schc_rule(): no device was found for this id");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < device->rule_count; i++) {
        struct schc_rule_t* curr_rule = (*device->context)[i];
        if(curr_rule->id == rule_id) {
            DEBUG_PRINTF("get_schc_rule(): %p %p \n", &schc_rule_2, curr_rule);
            return curr_rule;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

The rule I'm looking for is `schc_rule_2`, and is therefore present in the `DEBUG_PRINTF()` function.

The output of this function is

```
get_schc_rule(): 0x560e806f9bf0 0x560e806f9bf0
```

However, whenever I call this function from another function, like so

```
struct schc_rule_t* ptr = get_schc_rule_by_rule_id(rule_id, device_id);
DEBUG_PRINTF("schc_fragment_input(): rule ptr %p \n", ptr);
```

I get the following:

```
schc_fragment_input(): rule ptr 0xffffffff806f9bf0
```

The last 32-bits of the address seem to be correct, however the first 16 are not and leave me with a pointer I can not access. Any idea?

Comment: 64 bit embedded device? Which CPU would that be?

Comment: Are there different pointer types in your development environment, like near/far/huge? Maybe you need to specify the respective return and variable pointer types.

Comment: I also find your pointer to incomplete array type curious (I assume that is what it is): `*(*context)[]`. IIUC you could as well just use a pointer to pointer. Would that change anything?

Comment: @Lundin; it is a library that should run on both embedded and server device, so for now I'm developing on my pc

Comment: How is `DEBUG_PRINTF` implemented? Is it just a wrapper around `printf`?

Comment: @Lundin, yes `#define DEBUG_PRINTF(...)   printf(__VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I have been strugling with the `context` array.. I did not try to change it back since I managed to fix it

Comment: Ok well then it looks like some pointer compatibility issue across translation units, or some linker hiccup. Do you get the same issues if you place everything in a single file? Make sure to compile as C99 or later to rule out missing prototypes.

Comment: @Lundin very interesting.. when I place everything in a single file I get
```get_schc_rule(): 0x563ebd9f0bf0 0x563ebd9f0bf0 
schc_fragment_input(): rule ptr 0x563ebd9f0bf0```, any suggestions on how I should continue from here?

Comment: Either you are compiling as C89 after which you can get function incompatibility bugs. Or the structs aren't visible to all translation units, some of them taking them as incomplete type or similar. The problem seems to clearly be related to your project file structure though, and which files that see which functions/struct definitions. Start by with compiling as `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` or your compiler's equivalent strict standard setting, to rule out crap like c89, -std=gnu etc.

Comment: Are you cross-compiling ? In any case, make sure all compilation units are compiled with the same (relevant) flags (as for the working file eg.). Same for the linker flags.

Comment: I saw there was a `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘get_schc_rule_by_rule_id’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`, which converted the pointer to an `int` (`warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`) and led me to the fact that I forgot to include a file and it is now working fine. Thanks for the replies